# Use python library in java code

Tags: java, python, jython

There is some library called [pymorphy](http://packages.python.org/pymorphy/) written in python. Unfortunately, for java there is not any library with the similar functionality - natural language processing for Russian lang. So I need to invoke some methods of pymorphy library from Java code.

First I've tried to solve this problem with Jython. But I've spent 2 days and the goal was not accomplished because python modules cdb, bsddb3, sqlite are written in C and they will not work with Jython.

Now I want to run some python light-weight server with pymorphy for handling request from Java code.

How could I implement this kind of java-python interaction with the maximum production performance? Or is there more simple way to call python from java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Jepp, "Java Embedded Python". http://jepp.sourceforge.net/

I haven't used it beyond small projects, but it works as advertised, allowing one to call CPython transparently from Java.  If you have the opposite problem, needing to call Java from CPython, definitely check out JPype. I've used it extensively and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I think these libraries (cdb, bsddb3, sqlite) has a jython implementation in https://code.google.com/p/django-jython/ check it out